# compare datetime in find conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, compare

I am trying to get all users that are updated maximum 90 seconds ago:

```
User.find(:all, :include => { :core => :image }, 
      :conditions => ["updated_at > ?", Time.now - 90.seconds] )
```

But it doesn't work.

why?

how can i do?

thanks

Comment: no. but there are no results. i think that is wrong: 
"updated_at > ?", Time.now - 90.seconds

Comment: no, it's ok. what are `:core` and `:image`? is it right to pass an array to `:include`?

Comment: ops... "is it right to pass a `hash` to `:include`?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set config.time_zone in your environment.rb to anything other than UTC, you need to do

```
User.find(:all, :include => { :core => :image }, 
      :conditions => ["updated_at > ?", Time.now.utc - 90.seconds] )
```

I'm going to assume that image is an attribute of an association called core?

Comment: That will also depend on ActiveRecord time zone setting, won't it?

Comment: @Alex Like I said, "If you set config.time_zone in your environment.rb to anything other than UTC..." That's the ActiveRecord setting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to specify users.updated_at

Answer (score 0):

It can be time zone problem. Try to find out Time.now - 1.day, if it'll work, so set your Time.zone in application controller.

And second, you can try your construction without :include option if it cause your problem